# Calculating the surface area to calculate built-up area in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have made a project to find the builtup area particular city.
Here is the source code:

```
var cloud_masks = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');
var maskClouds = cloud_masks.landsatTOA();

//Loading India image, the extracting data for Haryana (a state in India) and then subsequently Ambala (a district in Haryana) 
var bands = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B10', 'B11'];
var india = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1UDdgOCf8DoRJ9bVm-UVbR6CqxtkJToLQjTFd0r0Z','geometry')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Name','India'))
.geometry();
var india_image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterBounds(india)
.filterDate('2014-02-01','2014-09-01')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.map(maskClouds)
.median();
var district = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1PA2zwArj8EsplrX9eMxJ2H_TICyyx855KPnbJhC1','geometry')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('name','Jodhpur'));
var haryana_image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterBounds(district)
.filterDate('2014-02-01','2014-04-01')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.map(maskClouds)
.median();
var input = haryana_image;
input = addBands(input.select(bands));
india_image = addBands(india_image);

//Loading the points from the fusion table and training the classifier
var ft = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1fWY4IyYiV-BA5HsAKi2V9LdoQgsbFtKK2BoQiHb0');
var ft_builtup = ft.filter(ee.Filter.eq('class',1)).limit(1200);
var ft_nonbuiltup = ft.filter(ee.Filter.eq('class',2)).limit(1800);
ft = ft_builtup.merge(ft_nonbuiltup);
var new_bands = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B10', 'B11','NDBI','NDVI'];

function addBands(image){
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  var ndbi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDBI');
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B6']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndbi).addBands(ndwi);
}

// Load a Landsat 8 image to be used for prediction.
var training = india_image.sampleRegions(ft,['class'],30);
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, 'class', new_bands);

input = input.clip(district);
input = input.classify(trained);
input = input.expression('LC==1?1:0',{'LC':input.select('classification')});
Map.addLayer(input.clip(district));

/*Export.image.toDrive({
  image: input.clip(district),
  description: 'Test',
  scale: 30
});*/
```

Now I want to calculate the surface area of built-up area and non built-up area which are in black and white pixels.